# How to get file upload progress from the code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to get the file upload progress in code Igniter.Please don't recommend any j-query integration as it is not the matter right now. Just give me a plain solution that could be done to get file progress in code igniter.
This is my code to uplaod pictures:

```
 $base=$this->config->item('base_url');
     $images=$this->config->item('images');

             $config['upload_path'] = './images/teacherimages';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo "Error<br>";
    }
    else
    {      
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

          $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
       $pic =   $upload_data['file_name'];

 $this->load->model('Teacher/InsertModel');

           $this->InsertModel->updatePic($pic,$id);

            }
```

Comment: I guess this is in a function / method from your controller ?
Can u paste the entire method please?

Comment: This is the whole code of my function doupload($id){//my code part that i pasted }